# Excel formula to count how many times a part number is used in a top level assembly (no UNIQUE or FILTER)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of part numbers that are used in 4 different top level assemblies. The parts can be used in 1 to 4 of the top level assemblies. I'm trying to write a formula that will count how many unique top level assemblies a part number occurs in. I had previously written a formula that worked, but it uses UNIQUE and FILTER, and my coworkers don't have Excel 365, so those formulas aren't supported for them. I've been trying to come up with a workaround and would really appreciate any help :)

I have an example (I can't provide any real data) section of our spreadsheet and an image of the formula I had that was working

| Top Level Assy | Part Number | Qty | Number of times used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02554 | 01622 | 4 | 3 |
| 89975 | 01622 | 4 | 3 |
| 95665 | 01622 | 4 | 3 |
| 98886 | 01723 | 4 | 1 |
| 98886 | 01723 | 10 | 1 |
| 98886 | 01723 | 4 | 1 |
| 02554 | 01734 | 4 | 3 |
| 89975 | 01734 | 4 | 3 |
| 95665 | 01734 | 4 | 3 |
| 02554 | 01740 | 6 | 3 |
| 89975 | 01740 | 6 | 3 |
| 95665 | 01740 | 6 | 3 |
| 02554 | 01746 | 5 | 3 |
| 89975 | 01746 | 5 | 3 |
| 95665 | 01746 | 5 | 3 |
| 02554 | 01835 | 2 | 3 |
| 89975 | 01835 | 2 | 3 |
| 95665 | 01835 | 2 | 3 |
| 02554 | 51205 | 4 | 3 |

=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, C:C=C2, "")))>0))

[Picture of the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pXLd.png)
[Picture of working formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maz9V.png)

Comment: Have you considered countifs() ?

Comment: Yes, I tried =COUNTIFS(C:C, C2, A:A, A2) dragged down, and it seemed to work for part numbers that were only used once or twice, but further down in the spreadsheet, where parts were used 3 and 4 times, it was showing 6, 9, and 16 instead of 3 and 4. I tried to diagnose it but I had no clue what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula in row 2: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$20=$B2,$A$2:$A$20),$A$2:$A$20)>0))`

*I think it doesn't require `ctrl+shift-enter` in older Excel versions, since SUMPRODUCT is an array formula by default.

The formula checks the frequency of values in column A where column B matches the value in the current row. It returns the count per unique value meeting the condition. Wrapping it in `--` & `>0` returns `1` for each unique value. SUMPRODUCT sums them.

**Edit:**
*I realized that the top level assembly values are actual text, not numeric values. In that case (since it's all numeric values stored as text) you can use this workaround:*
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$20=$B2,--($A$2:$A$20)),--($A$2:$A$20))>0))`

*It converts the text to numbers.*

*Sidenotes to this workaround:*

- *If any value would contain a character other than numeric it will not get counted.*
- *If you have both values like `02554` and `2554` they'll both get converted to `2554` and counted likewise.*

**Edit 2:**
For text use the following:
`=SUMPRODUCT(IF($B$2:$B$20=$B2, 1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$20, $B2, $A$2:$A$20, $A$2:$A$20)), 0))`

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! For future reference, if we have part numbers where, for example 02554 and 2554 were different parts, would that first formula you posted work?

Comment: Please see Edit 2 for text values